# Prove that $\sup\{f(x) : x < s\} ≤ \inf\{f(y) : y > s\}$ and both values are real numbers given an increasing function

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Suppose there's an increasing function $f : R → R,$ indicating that $f(x) ≤ f(y)$ whenever $x ≤ y.$

My question is: given $s ∈ R,$ how would I show that $\sup\{f(x) : x < s\} ≤ \inf\{f(y) : y > s\}$ and also that both values are real numbers ?

Comment: the left set is bounded above by $f(s)$ and the right set is bounded below by $f(s)$. both are non-empty so the sups and infs exist in the real numbers. every value in the left set is less than or equal to every value in the right set. see what you can do from there

Answer (score 1):

You have the inequality $f(x) \leq f(y)$ for all $x \leq y$, so take $x_n$ strictly increasing to $s$ and $y_n$ strictly decreasing to $s$. Necessarily $x_n < s < y_n$ for each $n$, so $f(x_n) \leq f(y_n)$, so $\sup\{f(x): x < s\} = \lim_n f(x_n) \leq \lim_n f(y_n) = \inf\{f(y): y > s\}$.